# CodeLite build options not highlighted: can't compile and test code (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: c, ide, compilation

I am able to compile with gcc but not from CodeLite GUI. The build tab is not highlighted so I can't click any option.

When I open CodeLite it tells me that a new version is available. However, when I download the .deb and try to open it with Ubuntu Software Center it just hang indefinatly.

How to compile and run a code within CodeLite GUI when options are all grayed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Eclipse IDE you need to create a workspace first and a new project where you will have the actual source code of your project.
Check this link,it will help you with configuring

http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/ProjectSettings

Comment: You can create a project without a workspace, codelite will add one automatically for you if you dont have any